# php design patterns, класс который считает количество своих вызовов

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Как написать класс который считает сколько раз его вызвали?

Comment: Определиться с понятием "вызвали" и написать.

Comment: И как именно вы его хотите использовать? Где собираетесь хранить "счетчик"? Зачем, в принципе, такой класс нужен?

Comment: @InDevX, где хранить счетчик вопроса возникать не должно от слова совсем, static поля в пхп никто не отменял.
По второй части вопроса - я использую "подобные" счетчики например для подсчета кол-ва SQL запросов, только в моем случае синглтон, и ведется подсчет вызова функии Query =) Но ровно с тем же успехом можно переделать без синглтона и считать кол-во созданных экземпляров(и допускать например на 1 запрос 1 экземпляр).

Comment: спасибо. очень помогли.

Comment: Можете скинуть пример такого кода со static?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков про "хранить" я не это имел ввиду, зачем нужен класс вопрос был для автора, как и остальные, ибо в 1 виде для всех задач это реализовать не получится. Это были просто Уточняющие/наводящие вопросы именно для автора, а не "зачем это вообще надо и для чего его использовать"

Comment: Пример вы всегда можете глянуть на php.net, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: Часто для таких целей используют аспектно-ориентированное программирование (AOP)